# I have a problem with run code on platform dotnet

Tags: c#, .net

When I write in console `dotnet run`, I get message about error

error:

```
..\main.cs(3,35): error CS0246: Не удалось найти тип или имя пространства имен "Window" (возможно, отсутствует директива using или ссылка на сборку). [..\2dgame.csproj]                                                      

Ошибка сборки. Устраните ошибки сборки и повторите попытку.
```

code:

```cs
using System;
using System.Windows;
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you translate that error message into English?

Answer (score 0):

Try to clean the project delete bin and obj folders and then rebuild.

Comment: Also from what directory you run the project

Comment: I've tried this

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

There's an error with the 'Window' object, the compiler is telling you to fix that. Then try to:

- Clean the Bin and Obj file.
- Run `dotnet run` in the same directory as the **.csproj** file.